# Project.json definition dnx451 vs .dotnet ( 4.51)

Tags: .net, dnx, .net-core

I've some 
In asp vnext I can define 3 Types of runtime

- dnxCore
- dnx451
- dotnet

In Project.json it looks like this:

```
"frameworks": 
{
    "dotnet": { },
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
}^
```

and the ui shors this

[image]

I assume the following:

**dnxCore** is the new .net Core Framework.

**dotnet** is the previous runtime

**dnx451:**
What is different when defining "dotnet" or "dnx451" in the project.json?

Shouldn't both run with the .net execution runtime?

Also depending on which project template i choose ( vNext ClassLib or vNext Console Lib) default contains one or the other.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Answering your question in a different way: A library should target environments which SDK its requires. If you do not require a SDK use `netstandard` (or before .NET Core RC2 `dotnet`).

- `dnxcore50` DNX SDK running on CoreCLR/CoreFx (**deprecated**, use `netcoreapp1.0` instead).
- `dnx451` DNX SDK running on .Net 4.5.1 (Desktop CLR / Full BCL and FCL) (**deprecated**, use `net451` instead).
- `net46` .Net Framework 4.6 SDK running on Desktop CLR / Full BCL and FCL.
- `uap10.0` UWP Windows 10 SDK running on .Net Native/CoreFx.
- `netcoreapp1.0` .NET Core 1.0 SDK running on CoreCLR/CoreFx.
- `netstandard1.5` (RC2, `dotnet` before) any pure IL code which declares its dependencies (System.Runtime (based) libraries instead of a PCL contracts). Framework dependencies are available for .Net 4.5.x onwards, .NET Core or UWP (System.Runtime based library set in different versions). As with RC2 `dotnet` is deprecated, use `netstandard` instead.
- `netstandard2.0` (.NET Core 2.0; ~JUN 2017) any pure IL code which rely solely of the feature set of the `netstandard.dll` which all platforms (.NET Core, .NET Framework, Xamarin, Mono, Unity3D) have to implement (or throw NotImplementedException). The `netstandard2.x` is roughly the BCL library of the .NET Framework (without FCL components like WMI, WinForms, WPF, WCF, WWF, ...). By compatability shims, most existing NuGet packages will automatically be `netstandard2.0`.

So if your library only has some algorithms or is not specific to the platform, use `netstandard` / `dotnet`. If any of your dependencies is restricted, this dependency will propagate up to the application (e.g. DNX, UWP, .Net46) which uses it.

I can only highlight like Malachi the article series of Oren. (he just wrote a new one: https://oren.codes/2015/07/29/targeting-net-core/ on the same topic).

ps: `dotnet` / `netstandard` is not a concrete runtime it is the abstraction of it. It is a target which in this case does not even specifiy a runtime but instead says: Anything which interprets IL correctly goes. For example `dnxcore5` is a target which specify a SDK(DNX) which has a specific runtime (CoreCLR). In this case you can make further assumptions about the runtime behavior (like usage of JIT, availability of x-plat implementation, etc.).

pps: be aware that the `dotnet` name was transformed into the term `netstandard` with the upcoming RC2 release. Also the complete DNX SDK was splitted up between the .NET Core and ASP.NET Teams. Therefore, the framework moniker for .NET Core (CoreCLR/CoreFx) is `netcoreapp1.0` while 99% of the ASP.NET stack are just libraries with `netstandard1.5`. The DNX monikers (`dnx451` and `dnxcore50`) where deprecated. When running ASP.NET Core on .NET Framework (instead of .NET Core) use `net451`. Heavy read for details: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md

ppps: Continiously be aware, that the `netstandard1.x` concept of dependency based contracts was not further developed but changed to one (huge) standard contract (32k APIs; `netstandard2.0`) which has to be implemented by all platforms including the upcoming .NET Core 2.0. This change has the advantage that most of the existing ecosystem of NuGet package (which refer `mscorlib` and friends) can be integrated into `netstandard2.0` packages by using an intermediate compatibility shims.

Comment: Is there any difference/advantage referencing dnx46 over net46?

Comment: Well... With net46 you could use winforms or wpf or wmi in your library. With dnx46 you can use ASP.net 5 in your library. But if you do not use a SDK feature you should target dotnet and allowing all potential target apps ... Including wpf and ASP.net 5 to use your library.

Comment: Why call it _dnxcore50_ instead of  _coreclr50_ or _clr451_ ?

Comment: Because dnx using the coreclr or the normal CLR.

Comment: Before i forget: clr451 is ambiguous with net451 and coreclr50 is naming concept wise bound to UWP

Comment: And here's the [official documentation](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md) to systematize what's in Thomas's answer. It shows not only what's already implemented, but also the plan for the future about naming and versioning this stuff.

Comment: btw there is also "dotnet5.4"  @Thomas could you extend your list?

Comment: I updated the answer in regards of netstandard as the dotnet successor. @BoasEnkler: I have not mentioned the versioning of dotnet but netstandard instead. @ buli accidently also included your link. Thanks for all the comments.

Answer (score 7):

**dotnet** targets a slew of .NET Core 4.6 compatibilities. [reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30763115/what-frameworks-are-available-in-asp-net-5-applications)

"dotnet This is the new .NET Core for packages that don’t have any app model requirements." - [reference link](http://oren.codes/2015/06/09/pcls-net-core-dnx-and-uwp/)

So by these definitions **dotnet** is the new runtime, not the previous one