# Reference to DNXCore5 Error, StringComparer .NET5

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

New to .NET5, so not sure if this is something simple or not.  I have 5 other projects in my solution, which all have this in the project.json file

```
"frameworks": {
    "net5": { }
}
```

I needed to reference net5 because i am using EntityFramework, and for some reason it wouldnt work if i had the default "dotnet".

Now my website project has a slightly different frameworks tag. I have included all of it encase i am missing something else, but as you can see it is referencing DNX5 and DNXCore5 (Not sure why)

```
{
    "webroot": "wwwroot",
    "version": "1.0.0-*",

    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta5"
    },

    "commands": {
        "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --config hosting.ini"
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "dnx50": { },
        "dnxcore50": { }
    },

    "publishExclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components",
        "**.xproj",
        "**.user",
        "**.vspscc"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "wwwroot",
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components"
    ]
}
```

But i have an error when i am trying to reference use

```
StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase
```

See the screenshot below

[image]

If i look under References in the project, it appears that the DMXCore is referenced correctly and appears, as you can see here

[image]

Comment: Right, so it's saying that that enum member isn't available under DNX Core, so you can't use it. I'm not quite sure why you're confused at the moment.

Comment: I can reference this in another project if i change the framework to "net5"? Maybe I just need to know when i should reference "net5" and when i should reference dnx50".  Sorry very new to it

Comment: Well if you don't need to support dnxcore (as opposed to dnx) just remove "dnxcore50" from your list of frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31539341/project-json-definition-dnx451-vs-dotnet-4-51) question for full details.

- `dnxcore50` - DNX SDK running on CoreCLR/CoreFx
- `dnx451` - DNX SDK running on .Net 4.5.1 (Desktop CLR / Full BCL and FCL)
- `net46` - .Net Framework SDK running on .Net 4.6 (Desktop CLR / Full BCL and FCL).
- `uap10.0` - UWP SDK running on .Net Native/CoreFx
- `dotnet` - any pure IL code which declares its dependencies (instead of a PCL contract). Framework dependencies are available for .Net 4.6, DNX or UWP.

For .NET 4.5 you need to use `dnx45` for ASP.NET projects and `net45` for other projects to target .NET 4.5 which is what I think you are doing according to your other question.